# Can not read data from the sqlite in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite

I checked from sqlitebrowser that I successfully created sqlite and inserted data to sqlite, but now my problem is I could not read data from sqlite. I am new to sqlite.

Should I open the sqlite first, and read it?  Where is wrong on my code below?

This code for open the existing sqlite.

```
-(void)openSqlite{
    NSString *docsDir = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Questiondata.db"];
    NSArray *dirPaths;
    _databasePath = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Questiondata.db"]];
    NSFileManager *filemgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    if ([filemgr fileExistsAtPath:_databasePath] == NO) {
        const char *dbpath = [_databasePath UTF8String];
        if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &_contactDB) == SQLITE_OK) {
            char *errorMessage;
            const char *sql_statement ="CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, NAME TEXT, ADDRESS TEXT, PHONE TEXT)";
            if (sqlite3_exec(_contactDB,sql_statement,NULL,NULL,&errorMessage) != SQLITE_OK) {
                NSLog(@"Failed to create the table");
            }
            sqlite3_close(_contactDB);
        }
        else{
            NSLog(@"Fail to open/create the table");
        }
    } 
}
```

This is code for read data from existing sqlite.

```
-(void)readData{
    NSLog(@"we came here");
    sqlite3_stmt *statement;
    const char *dbpath = [_databasePath UTF8String];
    if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &_contactDB)) {
        NSString *querySQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM Questions WHERE QuestionNumber = 1"];
        const char*query_statement = [querySQL UTF8String];
        if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(_contactDB, query_statement, -1, &statement, NULL)== SQLITE_OK) {
            if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) {
                NSString *addressfield = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement,0)];
                NSLog(@"finddata:%@",addressfield);

            }else{
                NSLog(@"notfinddatabase");
            }
            sqlite3_finalize(statement);

        }else{
            NSLog(@"failed to serache database");
        }
        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
        sqlite3_close(_contactDB);
         NSLog(@"not be here");
    }
}
```

Comment: Handling SQLite from scratch is a little bit tedious and hard to me. In my last project, I used [FDBM](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb) to handle sqlite and it really saves my time

Answer (score 0):

In openSqlite method

```
const char *sql_statement ="CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, NAME TEXT, ADDRESS TEXT, PHONE TEXT)";
```

and in your query

```
NSString *querySQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM Questions WHERE QuestionNumber = 1"];
```

table name and column name are not same.
Change in Place "`Questions`" with "`users`" . 
and also change "`QuestionNumber`" with the `table column`.

May be, it will helps you or feel free.

Answer (score 0):

`sqlite` doesn't report all errors until you start accessing the data. For example just about any filename and path will pass without errors.

First of all you must check that, the database is in the `Documents folder`?
 It's not there by default. 
Perhaps it's in the main bundle?

Try this:

```
 NSString *dbName = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"dbFile" ofType:@"db"];
```